# BufferedImage does not show after produced by SwingWorkers

Tags: bufferedimage, swingworker

I am creating a well - known Mandelbrot Fractal in my GUI and to speed up creating my image I have decided to use Swing Workers. In the method doInBackground() I am calculating the color for every pixel and I am putting all colors into array. In the method done() I am accessing the array and color each pixel with proper color. This way heavy calculations are done in different threads while coloring is done in EDT. I have just one problem with it - the ready pictures are not showed, even though I know they are stored in BufferedImage (I can save file to my hard drive, accessing the BufferedImage directly, or - while zooming - I am creating a deep copy of an BufferedImage - in this case I can see proper image). I am pretty new to Java but I want my application to be as good as possible. My code is below and here: http://pastebin.com/M2iw9rEY

```
public abstract class UniversalJPanel extends JPanel{

    protected BufferedImage image;
    protected Graphics2D g2d;

    protected int iterations = 100; // max number of iterations
    protected double realMin = -2.0; // default min real
    protected double realMax = 2.0;// default max real
    protected double imaginaryMin = -1.6; // default min imaginary
    protected double imaginaryMax = 1.6;// default max imaginary
    protected int panelHeight;
    protected int panelWidth;
    protected Point pressed, released; // points pressed and released - used to calculate drawn rectangle
    protected boolean dragged; // if is dragged - draw rectangle
    protected int recWidth, recHeight,xStart, yStart; // variables to calculate rectangle
    protected FractalWorker[] arrayOfWorkers; // array of Swing workers



    public abstract int calculateIterations(Complex c);
    public abstract double getDistance(Complex a, Complex b);

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        panelHeight = getHeight();
        panelWidth = getWidth();
        image =new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); // creating new Bufered image
        g2d= (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();



        arrayOfWorkers= new FractalWorker[getHeight()]; // create new worker for each row and execute them
         for(int q = 0; q < getHeight(); q++ ){
                arrayOfWorkers[q] = new FractalWorker(q);
                arrayOfWorkers[q].execute();
        }

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); // draw an image

    }   

// *** getters, setters, different code//

private class FractalWorker extends SwingWorker<Object, Object>{
    private int y;  // row on which worker should work now
    private Color[] arrayOfColors; // array of colors produced by workers
    public FractalWorker( int z){
        y = z;      
    }
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

        arrayOfColors = new Color[getWidth()];

        for(int q=0; q<getWidth(); q++){ // calculate and insert into array proper color for given pixel
            int iter = calculateIterations(setComplexNumber(new Point(q,y))); 
            if(iter == iterations){
                arrayOfColors[q] = Color.black;
            }else{
                arrayOfColors[q] = Color.getHSBColor((float)((iter/ 20.0)), 1.0f, 1.0f );
            }
        }           
        return null;
    }
    protected void done(){ // take color from the array and draw pixel
        for(int i = 0; i<arrayOfColors.length; i++){            
            g2d.setColor(arrayOfColors[i]);
            g2d.drawLine(i, y, i, y);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call g.drawImage(...) the current contents of the image are being drawn to the component. At that point the SwingWorkers have not completed their work as you start them immediately before the drawImage call. You should not start the SwingWorkers in the paintComponent method, if a paint request has been received then it is too late to start a long drawing process.

A better solution might be to create the BufferedImage when your program starts and then recreate it when the size of the component changes. You should then start the SwingWorkers whenever a redraw is required and call repaint() on the component when they have finished drawing.

Comment: How can I check if SwingWorkers have finished executing what is in done() method? And I am not sure what do you mean by creating BufferedImage when I start my program - I thought by calling the method paintComponent() I am doing so. " (...)and then recreate it when the size of the component changes." - I am not changing size of my components at all. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your program should not be calling the paintComponent method directly - Swing does that. Your program must be able to respond to any paintComponent calls quickly. This is why you must have an image ready and drawn before paintComponent starts. If the content of the image changes then you need to repaint the component by calling panel.repaint(), this will lead to Swing calling paintComponent.

To determine whether your SwingWorkers have finished you can set a boolean at the end of done() and then keep a list of all your workers and iterate over it checking the booleans.